# how to make initial configurations in git

Tags: git

I have joined a private repository for project sharing using git. What are the initial configuration I have to make locally( like username, pwd) to connect to the repository? How am i supposed to connect my local git with the repository? The repository provided me with the following git link `git@<domain>:<username>/<project>.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to download the repository locally just do:

```
git clone git@<domain>:<username>/<project>.git
```

I'd also recommend spending some time at the following git site to learn the basics: http://gitimmersion.com/